# Javascript/HTML Slider Chances for HTML Game

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a game in HTML where the more chances you have, the more numbers can be chosen for dice roll, and the less chances you have, the less numbers you can get for dice roll. What I am trying to do is make it so that the num-100 part of it can change like if the slider is set to 20, it will be 80-100, and if the slider is set to 80, it will be 20-100. I still can't find the fix to this, but here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'arial';
}
</style>
<body>
<h2>Roll Dice</h2>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Bet" id="bt" />&nbsp;<select id="rolltype"><option id="true">Over</option><option id="false">Under</option></select>&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="nkcsgo.roll(document.getElementById('rolltype').value, document.getElementById('bt').value);" /></p>
<p><input onchange="nkcsgo.chances();" id="chances" type="range" min="20" max="80" value="50"></p>
<p id="chancess">Your chances are 50%<br>Under: 1-50; Over: 50-100</p>
<p id="wallet">Wallet: $5.00</p>
<p id="status">Roll to see your win/loss...</p>
<script>
  var thechances = 50;
  var wallet = 5;
  var nkcsgo = {
    "chances": function()
    {
      document.getElementById('chancess').innerHTML = 'Your chances are ' + document.getElementById('chances').value + '%<br>Under: 1-' + document.getElementById('chances').value + '; Over: ' +  + '-100';
    },
    "roll": function(upp, bet)
    {
      bet = Math.floor(bet);
      if (wallet > 0 && bet <= wallet && bet > 0)
      {
        var currRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        if (upp == "Over")
        {
          if (currRoll >= 58)
          {
            // Congrats! You won!
            wallet += Math.abs(bet);
            document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = "Wallet: $" + wallet;
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "You rolled a " + currRoll + ", you gained $" + bet + ".00!";
          }
          else
          {
            // Sorry, but you lost.
            wallet -= Math.abs(bet);
            document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = "Wallet: $" + wallet;
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "You rolled a " + currRoll + ", you lost $" + bet + ".00.";
          }
        }
        else if (upp == "Under 1-30")
        {
          if (currRoll <= 42)
          {
            // Congrats! You won!
            wallet += Math.abs(bet);
            document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = "Wallet: $" + wallet;
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "You rolled a " + currRoll + ", you gained $" + bet + ".00!";
          }
          else
          {
            // Sorry, but you lost.
            wallet -= Math.abs(bet);
            document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = "Wallet: $" + wallet + ".00";
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "You rolled a " + currRoll + ", you lost $" + bet + ".00.";
          }
        } else {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "It seems you are trying to break the system.";
        }
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "You do not have enough funds or the number $" + bet + ".00 is invalid.";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based on what I see, the chances should affect the `over` and `under` limit. I would set 2 variables, to store this limits, and the chances moving that limit. for instance, if you have 20% chances, the over limit would be 90, instead of 58

Comment: The only thing in the code as of right now I am concerned about is the function nkcsgo.chances. I'm sure I can set some variables, I don't know the code to make this change to the right chances.

Comment: well the chances should `(100 - slider.value)`, assuming that's what missing between the 2 `+`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much, it works now :D